# How to read in Angular 2 the JSON #text

Tags: json, angular, angular2-forms

Sorry, but I'm stagnant to read a very specific JSON value in Angular 2&4, where I can obtain and showing the name of the list BUT! but I can't find a way to show in the page, what I'm talking about for example in the JSON document I have this way: (obtained from http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopAlbums ) and I'm using the Postman to check all the contents, I can obtain the name of the Album and other things, BUT to obtain the #text to use the image it's weird

```
"topalbums": {
    "album": [
      {
        "name": "The Very Best of Cher",
        "playcount": 1663904,
        "mbid": "a7e2dad7-e733-4bee-9db1-b31e3183eaf5",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Cher/The+Very+Best+of+Cher",
        "artist": {
          "name": "Cher",
          "mbid": "bfcc6d75-a6a5-4bc6-8282-47aec8531818",
          "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Cher"
        },
      **// +++++++++++++++++++THIS PART +++++++++++++++++++++!!!!!** 
        "image": [
          {
            // I'M TRYING TO USE THIS INFORMATION
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/34s/287bc1657795451399d8fadf64555e91.png",
            "size": "small"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/64s/287bc1657795451399d8fadf64555e91.png",
            "size": "medium"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/287bc1657795451399d8fadf64555e91.png",
            "size": "large"
          },
          {
            "#text": "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/300x300/287bc1657795451399d8fadf64555e91.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
          }
        ]
      },
```

What I want it's to obtain the "url" of the image, I try to obtain in this way:

**artist.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let list of albumes">
  {{list.name}}
  <hr>
  <!-- Can't obtain the URL... -->
  <img src="{{list.image[1].text}}" alt="">
</div>
```

**artist.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {MusicService} from "../../services/music.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-artist',
  templateUrl: './artist.component.html',
  providers: [MusicService]
})
export class ArtistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: MusicService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  albumes: any[];
  songs: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.map(params => params['mbid']).subscribe(
      mbid => {
        // Top Album
        this.service.GetTopAlbumArtist(mbid).subscribe(topalbum => {
          this.albumes = topalbum.topalbums.album;
          console.log(topalbum.topalbums.image);
        });
        // Top Tracks
        // this.service.GetTopTracksArtist(mbid).subscribe(toptracks => {
        //   this.songs = toptracks;
        // });

      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `src="{{list.image[0]['#text']}}"` or even better `[src]="list.image[0]['#text']"`?

Comment: omg THANKS !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to get the first position of `image` *array*, you should access the position 0 (not 1)... also you don't have `text` but `#text`:

To solve your problem you can do this way:

```
src="{{list.image[0]['#text']}}"
```

or even **better**:

```
[src]="list.image[0]['#text']"
```